# TypeScript two different event handlers calls the same function, but shouldn't

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two image picker elements in the from as shown bellow:

```
<input 
  accept="image/*"
  style={{ display: 'none'}}
  id="icon-button-file"
  type="file"
  onChangeCapture={ (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    onProfileImagePickHandler(e)
  } 
/>

<input
 accept="image/*"
 style={{ display: 'none'}}
 id="icon-button-file"
 type="file"
 onChangeCapture={ (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
  onBackgroundImagePickHandler(e)
 }
/>
```

I have two functions writtem for these image pick event, like the following:

```
const onProfileImagePickHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void =>
    {
        if (e.currentTarget.files?.item(0) )
        {
            const file = e.currentTarget.files.item(0);
            setProfileImageFile(file!);

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file!);
            reader.onload = async () =>
            {
                setProfileImage(reader.result as string);
            }
        }
    }

    const onBackgroundImagePickHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void =>
    {
        if (e.currentTarget.files?.item(0) )
        {
            const file = e.currentTarget.files.item(0);
            setBackgroundImageFile(file!);

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file!);
            reader.onload = async () =>
            {
                setBackgroundImage(reader.result as string);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the onProfileImagePickHandler function is get called both times! I can't see why?!

Comment: is content overlapping ?what happen if you comment one input ?

Comment: same happens, it is always calling the onProfileImagePickHandler function

Comment: probably because you have same id for both elements.use unique ids for example `icon-button-file` and `icon-button-files` or use a same classname if you want

Comment: It would be easier if you had an example showing on codesandbox.io same id may be the reason